# Maverick probe causes ardiuno to reset when touches grounded electrical item

Tags: arduino, power-supply, dc

I have a Maverick 732 probe connected to an Arduino for measuring temperature. The outer shield of the probe is connected to the ground pin on the Arduino, and the other wire is connected to an analog pin on the Arduino, and to a 220k ohm resistor and then 5V:

[image]

Using a variety of off the shelf 12v and 9v DC AC/DC adaptors to power the Arduino, the external wire of the probe touching an earthed appliance such as the metal shell of an electrical oven or a slow cooker causes the Arduino to reset.

The one thing that all of these transformers have in common is that they only have 2 real pins connected at the plug (UK 3 pin plug with a plastic pin where the earth pin would be or a metal pin with no earth wire connected). So the transformer is only connected to live and neutral at the plug socket.

On a power adaptor that uses a 3 pin plug and includes an earth connection in the plug, the resetting of the Arduino when the probe sheathe touches an earthed appliance does not happen. If I use a battery instead of a transformer, this issue also does not happen.

I then modified the transformer to include an earth connection to the outer part of the barrel connector (-) that provides power to the Arduino. This also solves the problem - the reset no longer occurs.

I don't understand what I can change in my circuit, short of using an earthed ac/dc adaptor to provide power to avoid this issue. Is there anything that can be done to stop this happening?

Comment: Part of the problem is that the probe is daisy chained through the Arduino: both the power and ground for the probe go through the Arduino circuit board, and so any sudden stray current from touching a grounded device affects the Arduino.  You should power the probe directly from the supply, bypassing the the Arduino. I.e. the power comes into some entry module which then distributes it to the Arduino and to the probe. If that doesn't fix the problem, then opto-isolation may be needed.

Comment: @Kaz Would that be as simple as something like the following: http://i.imgur.com/5xMJQsR.png ?

My concern with that is that I still have a common ground that is feeding both the Arduino (although the probe is no longer attached to the Arduino) and the probe.